# String.split more regex chars

Tags: java, string, split

i need to split my string into two, example:

```
String myString = "the_string";
String splitted[] = myString.split("_");
```

thats OK, but if my string contains this: `myString = "the____string";`
its not working, i dont know how to secure this, thanks;

Comment: learn about quantifiers.

Comment: So if the `String` contains **one or more `_`**?

Comment: yes, if the string contains one or more "_" chars

Comment: It's bolded for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

The delimiter argument to `String.split` is a regular expression. If you want to split on one of more underscores, use `myString.split("_+")`.

If you always want two elements in your result regardless of repeated instances of the delimiter, `myString.split("_+", 2)`

```
String a = "hello_there"
String b = "hello___there"
String c = "hello____there___how__are_you"

a.split("_+"); // -> ["hello", "there"]
b.split("_+"); // -> ["hello", "there"]
c.split("_+"); // -> ["hello", "there", "how", "are", "you"]

a.split("_+", 2); // -> ["hello", "there"]
b.split("_+", 2); // -> ["hello", "there"]
c.split("_+", 2); // -> ["hello", "there___how__are_you"]
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you mark the answer as correct, people who find this question in the future will know it worked for you.

Comment: @joews I think he has to wait 15 minutes

Comment: Ah cool. The comment was geniune, not fishing for reputation :D